# Oracle jdbc connection over two Linux computers

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jdbc

I have connected my two laptops using a cat5 cross ethernet cable. Both have linux ubuntu installed.

```
Lappi 1: $ ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.16 up
Lappi 2: $ ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.17 up
```

both connected via wired ethernet connection

```
ping lappi 1: $ ping 192.168.1.17
give bytes means working

ping lappi 2: $ ping 192.168.1.16
working
```

lappi 1 has oracle xe 10g installed on it.

I want to fetch some rows using lappi-2 from oracle database at lappi-1.

Here is code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class servertest 
{
    public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.16:1521:XE","scott","tiger");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "select  email_to from createemail";
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);  

        while(rset.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rset.getString(0));  
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        servertest obj = new servertest();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

It doesn't give me any error. but it also doesn't retrieve any rows. Sometimes I get an error "connection could not be established"...(occasionally) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem in the code. Maybe it does not return rows because there are not any. And it probably returns connection error, because the link is really down (maybe the cable is damaged...).

Java has very good error reporting, just read the message carefully. If it reports it cannot connect, be 99% sure that it is the network problem. If there are no rows, double check that you are selecting the right table etc.

Please follow Java Naming Conventions: class names start with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't give me any error.. but doesn't retrieve rows. Sometimes give
>   connection could not established error...(occasionally) ]

Sometimes? Check your network connection and ensure it has low latency. Also ensure firewall and port are open and are setup correctly for these two computers. Logically when the table is empty, the `ResultSet` return empty. So you should really check if your table has data in it.

Rather than throw the exceptions, why don't try and catch every specific of the exceptions? My point is that by catching every possible specific exception, you know exactly what is wrong. That strategy is good in your current situation. If it is `ClassNotFoundException` exception, print a useful message. If it is `IOException`, then print the useful message.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but neverethless here it is:

One problem I see in code and that should throw SQLException:
when you're fetching data you are getting column 0 (rset.getString(0))
in JDBC column & field indexes start from 1, not 0!